# Get HTTP error 500 when using the Watson Assistant

Tags: watson-assistant

Based on https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple

**That is the actual http request:**

```
// Built http request
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('POST', messageEndpoint, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status === 200 && http.responseText) {
        Api.setResponsePayload(http.responseText);
      } else if (http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && http.status !== 200) {
        Api.setErrorPayload({
          'output': {
            'generic': [
              {
                'response_type': 'text',
                'text': 'I\'m having trouble connecting to the server, please refresh the page, http response:' + http.status 
              }
            ],
          }
        });
      }
    };
```

The code is deployed locally on a Mac and started with *npm start*. The http error **500** is returned.

**Environment .env**

```
ASSISTANT_IAM_APIKEY=nc2FsZNKCFlxxxxx1U9jbQ7mF-fG6aEEu9m7NPyDdH4m
ASSISTANT_IAM_URL=https://api.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/e810a879-26c3-4dcb-a465-0xxxxx53fe09
ASSISTANT_ID=07e0bf57-1454-4adc-a2e4-96xxxxx9c969
```

Comment: I have a Lite plan, maybe that's the reason?